# JQUERY Ayuda con multiplicar valores de columnas y sumarlos los resultado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo esta tabla : el objetivo es multiplicar valor1(primer columna) y valor2(segunda columna) y el resultado (tercer columna), el después sumar cada uno de los resultados.

```html
<table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Valor1</th>
                    <th>Valor2</th>
                    <th>Valor1*valor2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>6</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>12</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Sumar de :</td>
                    <td> 18</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Si modificamos levemente tu tabla para estructurarla convenientemente con `<thead>`/`<tdata>`/`<tfoot>` se puede simplificar el trabajo de la siguiente manera:

- Si el primer y el segundo valor son numéricos (no son `NaN`) y existe una tercera columna, calculamos el producto y mostramos el resultado en ella.
- Acumulamos los resultados parciales para mostrarlos en la tercera columna del pie (si existe).

PD: Hacer el trabajo con o sin jQuery es prácticamente lo mismo.

### Implementación sin jQuery:

```js
var total = 0.;
/* Localizamos las filas de datos */
var filas = document.querySelectorAll('table tbody tr');
/* Por cada fila sumamos los datos de la primera y segunda columna */
filas.forEach(function (valor, indice) {
  /* Localizamos las celdas de datos */
  var celdas = valor.querySelectorAll('td');
  /* Si son valores numéricos y existe la tercera columna */
  if (
    ! isNaN(celdas[0].innerText)
  &&
    ! isNaN(celdas[1].innerText)
  &&
    celdas[2] !== undefined
  ) {
    /* Calculamos el producto, mostramos el resultado y lo agregamos al total */
    var suma = parseFloat(celdas[0].innerText) * parseFloat(celdas[1].innerText);
    celdas[2].innerText = suma;
    total += suma;
  }
});
/* Mostramos la salida */
var pie = document.querySelectorAll('table tfoot td');
if (pie[2] !== undefined) {
  pie[2].innerText = total;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Valor1</th>
        <th>Valor2</th>
        <th>Valor1*valor2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Suma:</td>
        <td>18</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

### Implementación con jQuery:

```js
var total = 0.;
/* Localizamos las filas de datos */
var filas = $('table tbody tr');
/* Por cada fila sumamos los datos de la primera y segunda columna */
filas.each(function (indice) {
  /* Localizamos las celdas de datos */
  var celdas = $( this ).find('td');
  /* Si son valores numéricos y existe la tercera columna */
  if (
    ! isNaN(celdas[0].innerText)
  &&
    ! isNaN(celdas[1].innerText)
  &&
    celdas[2] !== undefined
  ) {
    /* Calculamos el producto, mostramos el resultado y lo agregamos al total */
    var suma = parseFloat(celdas[0].innerText) * parseFloat(celdas[1].innerText);
    celdas[2].innerText = suma;
    total += suma;
  }
});
/* Mostramos la salida */
var pie = $('table tfoot td');
if (pie[2] !== undefined) {
  pie[2].innerText = total;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Valor1</th>
        <th>Valor2</th>
        <th>Valor1*valor2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Suma:</td>
        <td>18</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```